# Nested resource: controller spec doesn't call the wanted action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, nested, specifications

I have a `ReportsController`, nested in `ProjectsController`, with a `#show` method:

```
def show
  # Some stuff

  do_something(@report)
end
```

Routes:

```
resources :projects do
  resources :reports
end
```

I need to test that the `do_something` method is called:

```
  it 'calls do_something' do
    expect(controller).to receive(:do_something)

    project = create :project
    report = create :report, project: project

    get :show, params: {project_id: project.id, id: report.id}
  end
```

I placed `binding.pry` within the `#show` action, but this doesn't get called. So what's wrong with my spec?

Comment: Is your spec named correctly?

Comment: What do you mean with this? It's like `describe ReportsController do ... end`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I wasn't logged in:

```
  before do
    @user = create :user, :admin
    sign_in_as @user
  end
```